# Changing the visibility of PreferenceCategory elements in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the PreferenceCatergory elements to make a fragment dedicated to the setting of a Bluetooth device controlled by the android application.
However, not all devices have all the same sensors and I would like to hide the settings if the current connected devices does not have one of the specific sensors.

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Accelerometer sensor">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="accelerometer_checkbox_enviro"
        android:summary="Set the sensor on or off"
        android:title="On/Off" />
    <wibicom.wibeacon3.SliderDialog
        android:title="Period"
        android:summary="Set the refreshing rate of the sensor"
        android:dialogMessage="Set the refreshing rate of the accelerometer sensor"
        android:dialogTitle="Set sensor period"
        android:key="accelerometer_period_enviro" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

This is one of the components of the PreferenceScreen.
Is there a way for me to make this invisible?
I read about the

```
myPreferenceScreen.removePreference(myPreference);
```

method. However, If I want this comonent to appear again the above line wouldn't be very practical.

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. Update your question with a concrete problem within your code. As of now, your question is in risk of downvoting and/or closure.

Comment: @DavidG I tried adding some code and be more clear on the question I had.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "hide". If you mean "enable/disable", just activate/deactivate the code in question with an `If` statement, depending on the sensors of the device.

Comment: @DavidG By hide, I meand I would like it to completely be invisible from the screen. Is the only way to do so removing it from the layout?  Or would "deactivate" the code do exactly this?